# How to calculate a rolling correlation coefficient between 2 columns in a pandas dataframe with groupby?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe:

```
df=pd.dataframe({'group':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],'val1':[100,200,300,400,50,150,250,350,50,150,250,350,100,200,300,475],'val2':[3,5,10,-3,2,-5,89,12,35,5,10,-3,2,-5,89,12]})
```

I want to calculate the correlation coefficient between columns 'val1' & 'val2' with a rolling window of 3 and within each groups. I would like to add this as a column to the dataframe. I'm able to do this without using a groupby:

```
df['val1'].rolling(5).corr(df['val2'])
```

But I'm not able to incorporate the same with a groupby.

Output I'm looking for is a column added to the original df like this:

| group | Val1 | Val2 | Correlation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 3 | Nan |
| A | 200 | 5 | Nan |
| A | 300 | 10 | Nan |
| A | 400 | -3 | Nan |
| A | 50 | 2 | 0.1 |
| A | 150 | -5 | -0.25 |
| A | 250 | 89 | 0.8 |
| A | 350 | 12 | 0.65 |
| B | 50 | 35 | Nan |
| B | 150 | 5 | Nan |
| B | 250 | 10 | Nan |
| B | 350 | -3 | Nan |
| B | 100 | 2 | -0.43 |
| B | 200 | -5 | 0.23 |
| B | 475 | 89 | 0.87 |
| B | 100 | 12 | 0.65 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by column `group`.  The result will be 2 groups each with all rows (even for rows not belonging to the group). Then, further combine the results of different groups by aggregating with [`.GroupBy.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) on the original row index, as follows:

```
df['Correlation'] = df.groupby('group')['val1'].rolling(5).corr(df['val2']).groupby(level=1).max()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   group  val1  val2  Correlation
0      A   100     3          NaN
1      A   200     5          NaN
2      A   300    10          NaN
3      A   400    -3          NaN
4      A    50     2    -0.136808
5      A   150    -5     0.051931
6      A   250    89     0.093510
7      A   350    12     0.079207
8      B    50    35          NaN
9      B   150     5          NaN
10     B   250    10          NaN
11     B   350    -3          NaN
12     B   100     2    -0.652637
13     B   200    -5    -0.210248
14     B   300    89     0.328695
15     B   475    12     0.152914
```